# Шорткод с аттрибутами, в которых есть пробел

Tags: php, wordpress

По умолчанию wordpress разбивает параметры шорткода по пробелу, т.е. допустим

```
[test param1='1' param='2']
```

создаст такие параметры: `param1` и `param`,
а если прописать такое:

```
[test param='{{category}} url-{{url}}']
```

тогда wordpress разобъёт параметры по пробелу, и получится такие параметры:
`0=>param` и `1=>url`, т.е. ключи будут числовые, а нужны символьные.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно обработать вышеприведённый шорткод, в котором пробелы?  т.е. нужно получить атрибут param, в котором есть `{{...}}` и заменить на нужные значения.
Т.е. нужно в теле функции шорткода заменять все значения `{{...}}` на нужные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего подобного. WordPress сам по себе не разбивает ничего по пробелу.

Вот пример одного из моих шорткодов:

```
[map center="61.58275344395224, 98.82752168749995" zoom="4" width="100%" height="86vw" ... и тут еще куча параметров ... ]
```

В коде:

```
function map_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $center = $atts['center'];
  ...
}
```

и строка $center принимает значение "61.58275344395224, 98.82752168749995"

Если внутри шорткода необходимо использовать квадратные скобки, их надо экранировать:

```
[test param="\[cool\]"]
```

В коде:

```
function test_shortcode( $atts ) {
  $param = $atts['param'];
  ...
}
```

Строка $param примет значение "[cool]".

Comment: согласен. Но дело в том, что мне нужно ещё указывать в квадратных кавычках дополнительный параметр, как я привёл ниже. Из-за этого получается ошибка и ваш код уже не будет работать.  Извиняюсь, что сразу про это не сказал, почему-то решил, что и без квадратных скобок будет такая же ошибка
`[map center="61.58275344395224, 98.82752168749995[test]"]`

Comment: т.е. [test] нужно ещё дополнительно обрабатывать регулярным выражением и вытаскивать значение в квадратных скобках

Comment: тогда, да, тут проблема не в пробелах, а в скобках

Comment: Экранировать надо. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Опечатка: вторая квадратная скобка в примере должна быть левой...

Comment: То есть, правой)) Спасибо, поправил)